# Problema de troca de servidor

Tags: php, linux

Eu tinha um site com um sistema em um servidor, precisei migrar para outro e agora aparece erro em quase todas as funções PHP do sistema. Eu já dei as permissões nas pastas, já que esta hospedado em linux, porém não consigo mesmo assim.

Quando tento criar uma conta nova, por exemplo ele da os seguintes erros:

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to
>   autors.com.br:587 (Connection refused) in
>   /home/storage/1/f2/68/autors/public_html/smtp.class.php on line 134
>   erro 222  Warning: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream
>   resource in /home/storage/1/f2/68/autors/public_html/smtp.class.php on
>   line 122

Comment: Dê mais informações, poste os erros na sua pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeAbreu, coloque esses novos detalhes na sua pergunta por favor

Comment: Seu problema está ocorrendo na rotina de email. Conexões estão sendo recusadas no autors.com.br porta 587 (porta SMTP - mail submission). Não tem relação com permissão de arquivos, como sugerido.

Comment: Aproveite e trate suas urls, possivelmente vulnerável a Sql injection.